# Optimize bash script to process bulk data

Tags: git, bash

When we clone the git repository from remote to local, all files get the timestamp (date) of local file system. I need a script that updates these files with the commit date in remote git repository. Have tried below script to do this job but it takes a lot time while processing 1000 files. Is there a way to optimize this?

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n\b'    
list_of_files=($(git ls-files | sort))  

for file in "${list_of_files[@]}"; do
    file_name="$file"
    TIME=$(git log --pretty=format:%ci -n 1 -- "$file_name")    
    touch -m -d $TIME "$file_name"
done
```

Comment: For a start your she-bang is incorrect, spaces are not allowed it should be `#!/bin/bash`. Also rather than stating an `X-Y` problem (explaining why your code is not working/taking time), explain us your requirement to get more reasonable responses. (and) `file_name=$(echo $file)` is an anti-pattern. You can just use `"$file"`

Comment: @Inian updated description with your suggestions.

Comment: There is _no_ ideal way to speed up this script, except may be using process-substitution (`<()`) to feed the files, instead of using an array. But no sure how much of a time it would save for 1000 files. You should post this in codereview SE site because, in its current state, it is not relevant in StackOverflow

Comment: I guess your bottleneck is the git call. Can you get the information about the date in another way?

Comment: @rakwaht Can you suggest an alternative way?

Comment: each commit in git update the whole tree to find for each file the last commit needs to run the log on each file maybe order of commands could be change first go backward in log and touch files until all files are touched

Comment: `git log --name-status` would print you updated files at each commit.  It's enough to accomplish your task, but it's going to be hard with just bash. I think it should be doable with `awk`

Comment: BTW, the way you're generating `list_of_files` is going to behave badly when you have filenames with spaces or glob characters in their names. Much better to use `readarray -t list_of_files < <(git ls-files | sort)`. (I'd describe even that as a bad practice in many circumstances, since files on UNIX can have literal newlines in their names, so you can't safely store a list of arbitrary files with newline delimiters -- NULs are the only safe one -- but I want to say git is more restrictive).

Answer (score 0):

It can be improved with bash associative arrays (by running first through the logs)

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A files_last_mod_time=() || exit 1

while read f; do files_last_mod_time[$f]=0; done < <( git ls-files | sort)

while IFS=, read chash ctime; do
    all_def=1
    for k in "${!files_last_mod_time[@]}"; do
        [[ ${files_last_mod_time[$k]} = 0 ]]&&all_def=0&&break
    done
    ((all_def==1))&&break
    echo "# processing commit hash: $chash, time: $ctime"
    while read f; do
        [[ ${files_last_mod_time[$f]} = 0 ]]&&{
            cmd=(touch -m -d "$ctime" "$f")
            echo "${cmd[@]}"
            "${cmd[@]}"
            files_last_mod_time[$f]=$ctime
        }
    done < <(git diff --name-only $chash^!)

done < <( git log --date-order --pretty=format:%H,%ci )
```

First answer below

it would be easier to do it in a language which support better hash than bash associative arrays, bellow an example with perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

%files_last_mod_time = map { $_ => '0' } `git ls-files | sort`;

for $commit_time (`git log --date-order --pretty=format:%H,%ci`) {
    last if !grep $_ eq '0', values %files_last_mod_time;
    chomp $commit_time;
    ($chash,$ctime) = split ",", $commit_time;
    print "# processing commit hash: $chash, time: $ctime\n";
    for $file (`git diff --name-only $chash^!`) {
        if (defined $files_last_mod_time{$file} && $files_last_mod_time{$file} eq '0') {
            ($file_in_cmd = $file) =~ s/'/'\\''/g;
            chomp $file_in_cmd;
            $cmd = "touch -m -d '$ctime' '$file_in_cmd'\n";
            print $cmd;
            system $cmd;
            $files_last_mod_time{$file} = $ctime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IFS= read -r f` rather than `read f` -- that way you can handle filenames with leading or trailing whitespace and/or embedded backslashes.

Comment: And `${!files_last_mod_time[@]}` needs to be in double-quotes to prevent string-splitting.

Comment: `${cmd[@]}` needs double quotes surrounding as well. (I'd probably add them in a bunch of other places as well and add more whitespace for readability). By contrast, `echo ${cmd[@]}` is arguably bad practice no matter what: Even if you *do* add the quotes, there's no possible way to tell the difference between `cmd=( "foo bar" )` and `cmd=( "foo" "bar" )` from its output. If you want to generate an unambiguous string representation of an array, `printf '%q ' "${cmd[@]}" && printf '\n'`

Comment: (BTW, do you *really* need to fork off a subprocess to run the `touch` from perl? It'd be much more efficient if that could be done in-process, not to mention less vulnerable to attacks via filenames containing `$(...)` literals or other shell syntax).

Comment: hi @CharlesDuffy, thank you for the feedback, indeed, i wrote it rapidely and tested and it worked it but i agree with all points, updating my answer

Comment: touch could be avoided in perl but it needed to format date and time which was a little more effort

Comment: also i didn't change the possibility to have leading/trailing spaces and backslashes in filenames because if project contains such files it will have other problems, perl version can't handle spaces in filename because not chomp, indeed solution is given as an example an should be improved